# Retrieving deeply nested data in Symfony 3 Parameterbags

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 2 you could do something like this to get nested query string data:

```
// mixed getInt(string lookup, mixed default, bool deep)
$request->query->getInt('page[number]', 1, true);
```

In Symfony 3 it looks like the ability to retrieve deeply nested data has been removed in favour of retrieving the top level array and getting the data directly.

```
// mixed get(string key, mixed default)
(int) $request->query->get('page', ['number' => 1])['number']
```

Can anyone confirm that I'm not missing something here and this is now the preferred method to retrieve nested data in parameter bags?

I did look over the 3.1 docs and all examples reference retrieval of the array with no options to query for deeply nested data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [PropertyAccess component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html):

```
$query = $request->query->all();

$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

$page = (int) $accessor->getValue($query, '[page][number]');
```

Comment: Ok that's interesting, I'll look into it a bit more, though I think this would be good on slightly more complex access problems than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpeler is

```php
$request->query->all();
```

This will return an array for your case like:

```
page => [
   number => 1
]
```

This works for all symfony versions.